# DRF 3.0.1: .create() method does not support writable nestedfields

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I just updated to Django REST Framework 3.0.1 and my tests are failing with [this addition](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/2196) to improve checks for nested creates and updates (`The .create() method does not support writable nestedfields by default.`), but as far as I know I'm not attempting to do any nested writes. I have one related Serializer, but it is set to `read_only=True` and when I post to this endpoint, the related objects all already exist. Any ideas, or am I just doing something wrong?

```
class Like(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user", "content_type", "object_id"),)


class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Like


class LikeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Like.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

printed LikeSerializer

```
LikeSerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    user = UserSerializer(default=CurrentUserDefault(), read_only=True):
        email = EmailField(
            allow_blank=True, 
            allow_null=True, 
            max_length=75, 
            required=False, 
            validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())>])
        id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
        username = CharField(
            help_text='Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', 
            max_length=30, 
            validators=[<django.core.validators.RegexValidator object>, 
            <UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())>])
        fullname = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, max_length=80, required=False)
        original_photo = ImageField(allow_null=True, max_length=100, required=False)
        about = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, required=False, style={'type': 'textarea'})
        user_following_count = ReadOnlyField()
        user_followers_count = ReadOnlyField()
        content_type = SerializerMethodField()
    created = DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    object_id = IntegerField(required=True)
    content_type = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ContentType.objects.all(), required=True)
    class Meta:
        validators = [<UniqueTogetherValidator(queryset=Like.objects.all(), fields=('user', 'content_type', 'object_id'))>]
```

I'm just posting the `object_id` and `content_type` of the object I want to like. Was working fine before I updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following this up as an issue, here... https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/2196#issuecomment-66839296